# Print the string using dynamically memory allocated

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

> Hello, my question is: How to print out string 1 and string 2, not only string 2. I am new to dynamically memory allocated. My sample code is below, thanks for your help.
>
> Result expected:
>
> Hello
>
> My name is Ken

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n, i;
    char *ptr;
    
    printf("How many strings you want to display?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    ptr = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(n));
    
    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("Failed to allocate the memory to string!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("String %d: ", i + 1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]", ptr);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Strings you entered:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only allocating one buffer and storing every string into that same buffer. So of course you only print the last input. You need to allocate multiple buffers and store into each string into a seperate buffer.

Comment: Why fflush(stdin)?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code. I have marked modified lines with a comment starting with `// CHANGE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// CHANGE - free memory when not needed
void free_memory(char** ptr, int n)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i])
            {
                free(ptr[i]);
            }
        }
        free(ptr);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, i;
    char **ptr; // CHANGE - make a double pointer - array of strings (imagine rows and columns)
    
    printf("How many strings you want to display?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    
    ptr = (char**) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));    // CHANGE - allocate memory based on no. of rows (columns are string characters)
    
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate the memory to string!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    getchar();  // CHANGE - read the newline character else fgets doesn't work
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ptr[i] = (char*) malloc(256 * sizeof(char)); // CHANGE - allocate memory for each row
        
        printf("String %d: ", i + 1);
        if ( fgets(ptr[i], 256 * sizeof(char), stdin) == NULL ) {
            printf("Failed to get line input\n");
            free_memory(ptr, n);
            exit(1);
        }
        ptr[i][strlen(ptr[i]) - 1] = '\0';  // CHANGE - remove extra newline character at the end
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Strings you entered:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr[i]); // CHANGE - print each row
    }
    free_memory(ptr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the memory used up be freed even if `fgets` returns error?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are two numbers that should be decided:

1. the number of strings the user wants to input and
2. the length of the strings (or the lengths of each string).

Each string will be stored in a `char*`. And all strings together will be stored in a `char**`. The length of `char**` will be your `n` in this case.
And length of each `char*` can be decided however you want.
I prefer to use a directive `#define` to define a constant like 100.
You can also do a global or local variable or just a digit.
Also don't forget to free anything you allocate. Check below for details.
And happy coding!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100

int main(){
    int n, i;
    // stores all the strings
    char **ptr;
    
    printf("How many strings you want to display?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    // allocate memory of size (n * size of char*)
    ptr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("Failed to allocate the memory to string!\n");
        // for portability to use EXIT_FAILURE, 
        // which is defined in the standard library
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // for each pointer, allocate memory of size (MAX_STRING_SIZE * size of char)
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        // I should put a validity check here but I'm too lazy...
        ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("String %d: ", i + 1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%[^\n]", ptr[i]);        // use ptr[i]
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Strings you entered:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);         // use ptr[i]
    }

    // free all of them
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program should always return 0 if no error was there, to indicate that the program succeeded (just a universal return value to bring uniformity). So when you encounter an error, you should either return 1 or 2. Here is a complete list- https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: @user1234 True. Thanks for pointing that out! I wasn't being careful.

Comment: Please read the attached link for reference. You are now returning `-1`, but exit codes must be in between 0-255.

Comment: @user1234 I'm not getting that exit codes must be in between 0-255. If I'm not wrong, this is a Bash-Scripting Guide. In terms of the language C, the standard doesn't say anything about exit function cannot be anything outside 0-255 and the signature of exit says it takes an `int`, not an `unsigned char`.  For portability of C code, using `EXIT_FAILURE` is better though. I'm changing my answer to exit with `EXIT_FAILURE`.